# Excel NETWORKDAYS not giving correct result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

to determine how long a ticket has been open, I have a created date and a closed date

I want to exclude holidays and weekends, so I am using excel's NETWORKDAYS functions

for
[image]

It is giving me back a result of 2 days and 9 minutes with the formula of...

`=MIN(INT([@[Closed Date]])-INT([@[Created Date]]),NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25))+MOD([@[Closed Date]]-[@[Created Date]],1)`

The Holidays I am using that are relevant here are 12/22/23 and 12/25/23

Days that fall on weekends are 12/23/23 and 12/24/23

So it should be getting back only 1 day 9 minutes

I have tried many different formula versions online.

I understand the logic of NETWORKDAYS sees 12/21 and 12/26 and 2 full work days, and that it why it is returning a '2' as a result, but how do I get it to return the difference of the mentioned dates/times

Comment: Should be like this: `=NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)+
NETWORKDAYS([@[Closed Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)*
(MOD([@[Closed Date]],1)-1)-
NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Created Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)*
MOD([@[Created Date]],1)`

Answer (score 1):

`=NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)` returns the number of whole days between the two dates.  But you want just part of the first and last days - the 12:53 remaining in the Created Date, and the 11:16 at the start of the Closed Date.

So the first and last days of the NETWORKDAYS should be removed from the calculation:
`=NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)-2`.

The hours remaining in Created Date can be calculated as:  `=INT([@[Created Date]])+1-[@[Created Date]]`.
The hours at the start of Closed Date can be calculated as:  `=[Closed Date]-INT([Closed Date])`.

These times just need added to the NETWORKDAYS, after the start and end dates have been removed:

```
=NETWORKDAYS([@[Created Date]],[@[Closed Date]],Holidays!$AF$10:$AF$25)-2+(INT([@[Created Date]])+1-[@[Created Date]])+([Closed Date]-INT([Closed Date]))
```

This will probably return an incorrect value if NETWORKDAYS isn't returning at least 2 days on its own.